# How to include a file that defines constants in a class (and it's scope)

Tags: php, class, oop, include, constants

Say we have the following:

**some.class.php**

```
class
{
    public __construct()
    {
        fun_stuff();
    }

}
```

**configuration.inc**

```
const SOMECONST = 1;
const SOMEOTHERCONST = 2;
```

I am looking to do something like this:

**some.class.php**

```
class
{
    public __construct()
    {
        include_once(configuration.inc);
        fun_stuff();
    }

}
```

Now this works, but the constant is not defined within the scope of the class (`echo some::SOMECONST;`) but rather in the global scope (`echo SOMECONST;`)

I *really really* want to have the constants in another file as it makes a lot of sense in my case. Is there a way to declare the constants in the scope of the class? I know it's impossible to use `includes` or `requires` inside the class definition so i'm at a loss.

Comment: One issue you will run into is that you are trying to do this in the constructor - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145198/how-to-define-constant-in-class-constructor.

Comment: It is also impossible to include a file in the class definition (ie putting the include inside the class, but ouside a function)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class.

Comment: That's why i said "I know it's impossible to use includes or requires inside the class definition"

Comment: The only way I see to do this, is by not using const but using normal static variables instead. Your include file could changed to `self::SOMEVAR = 1` and it should work.

Comment: @Scott I thought it would but it doesn't seem to. It throws a syntax error complaining about the "="

Comment: If you hadn't a cluttered name space, you could define constants in a namespaced file that you include.  A little better than global, but not to the scope of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it is not possible without extensions to php. I ended up just defining the consts in the class file its self.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest possibilty is to define your constant in one class and let your other class extend that class.

```
class myClassConstant {
  const SOMECONST = 1;
  const SOMEOTHERCONST = 2;
}

class myClass extends myClassConstant {

  public function __construct() {
    echo self::SOMECONST . ' + ' . self::SOMEOTHERCONST . ' = 3';
  }
}

$obj = new myClass(); // Output: 1 + 2 = 3
```

If you are using php autoloader this can easily be split up into two different files.

Comment: Although not an answer to my question, this seems like the most logical and viable way to accomplish what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: IMHO the best and most robust solution possible. It's a pitty that traits don't allow constants as that would be a really cool and elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357985/php-traits-defining-generic-constants

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public $config;

    public __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        fun_stuff();
    }

    public function Bar()
    {
        echo $this->config['baz'];
    }

}

$foo = new Foo(include_once 'config.php');
```

config.php

```
<?php
return array('baz' => 'hello earth');
```

It's not very explicit though.  There are no contracts on the config.

Comment: class properties are not the same as class constants