# PHP - include or require doesn't work at class file at oop

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

If I keep constant at **DB.php** Then everything works.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
class DB {
    private static $pdo;
    private $table = 'student_info';
    public static $name;
    public static $dep;
    public static $age;
    public static function connection(){
            try{
                self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.'; dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
            }catch( PDOException $e ){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        return self::$pdo;
    }

    public static function prepareOwn($sql){
        return self::connection()->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function readAll(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
        $stmt = self::prepareOwn($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    public function setValue($name, $dep, $age){
        self::$name = $name;
        self::$dep = $dep;
        self::$age = $age;
    }

    public function insertValue(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (name, department, age) VALUES (:name, :department, :age)";
        $stmt = self::prepareOwn($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', self::$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':department', self::$dep);
        $stmt->bindParam(':age', self::$age);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

But the problem is when I keep **constant** at separate file like **config.php** and **include or require config.php file at DB.php** then I get  **Notice: Use of undefined constant** when I try to use **spl_autoload_register()** at **index.php** page.

I don't know what is the problem actually. Why it isn't not working?? I want to know the logic.

Comment: check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087017/how-to-include-a-file-that-defines-constants-in-a-class-and-its-scope/35087402

Comment: Could you provide a part of the code you using to initiate the connection for better understanding?

Comment: **config.php** codes are

`<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'php-dev3');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');`

spl_auto_load_register() using

`<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        include 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
    });
    $new = new DB;`

Comment: Are you sure that  you are using `$new = new DB;` but not `$new = new DB();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using your constant before using of your class. Your `config.php` will be included only when you will try to use DB class - so autoloader will include `DB.php` (and then `config.php` will be included too).

Comment: I am using constant to make connection. So I am not using it before DB class